# How to add a column to a touple of maps dataset in apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to learn apache pig, hadoop and friends, for now I'm working with New York City ticket data.

I load data by:

```
data = load 'nyc/smallNYC.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS 
(
  SummonsNumber:int,
  PlateID:chararray,
  RegistrationState:chararray,
  PlateType:chararray,
  ...
  StreetName:chararray
  ... // And a lot more
)
```

Now I'd like to add two new columns to this dataset (or attach two new keys to each dataset), one would be `CleanedStreetName` (for the sake this question assume that I want to generate this column using: LOWER(StreetName)), second column would be `IssueYear`.

Then I'd like to filter, group and so forth using these columns, I couldn't find any guide that explains how do do this using.

So here are the questions:

- Is this a sensible thing to do? Maybe I should calculate these values on the fly?
- If this is is a sensible thing, please post a snippet that adds `CleanedStreetName` column.

Comment: You want to generate two new columns(CleanedStreetName and IssueYear) on the fly based on some filter condition in the existing inputs? If Yes then its possible. can you paste your sample input data and your final output?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pig you use `FOREACH` to generate projections of the data.

You didn't specify how you want to get IssueYear so I just assigned it as 0

```
NEWDATA = FOREACH data GENERATE *,LOWER(StreetName) as CleanedStreetName, 0 as IssueYear
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about `as`.